# Java How to reference an array in a method without passing as an argument

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on an assignment and am not sure if it would be ok to post my code here but I will try my best to explain my problem. I have to write a class that accepts an array of student answers from a seperate program and compares that array against an array of correct answers which I initialised in the class I am writing. The class then calculates the amount of correct and incorrect answers through methods which are then sent back to the program to output the results. The part that I am having trouble with is the method which I have to make which creates an array that stores the question number of the questions the student got wrong. I have used for loops to compare the two arrays in the constructor and initialised a new array to store the question numbers that correlate with the incorrect responses, normally i would just pass the array as an argument in the method header, but the program that the class works with has defined the method as having no arguments and I don't know any other way to pass an array from the constructor to a method. Sorry if this question sounds stupid, it probably is but I have been working on this for longer than I would like to admit. Basically I am just wondering if there is any way to access an array initialised in the constructor from a method without passing as an argument?

```
public class Example {
    private char[] correctAnswers;
    private char[] studentAnswers;
    private int count = 0;

    // Constructor accepts an array of answers from the other program.
    public Example(char[] answers) {
        char[] correctAnswers = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        int question_number = 1;
        int[] missed = new int[3];
        // Copy answers array to studentAnswers array
           *Insert code here 

       //Using a for loop I Compare the two arrays studentAnswers and 
       //correctAnswers and increment variables count and question_number
       //and if a question is wrong I populate the missed array with 
       // the question_number
          *Insert code here*

       public int totalCorrect() {
           return count;
           }

       public int[] totalIncorrect() {
           incorrect = 3 - count;
           return incorrect;
           }

       // This method can't accept any arguments
       public int[] questionsMissed() {
           return missed; // How do I access this array which is 
                          // initialised in the constructor?
           }
```

Comment: it is okay to post code here..

Comment: Use a blank line and 4 spaces to get code formatting :)

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: try to simplified explanation and put your code with that otherwise it seams like some one is reading essay

Comment: It is possible to access an array initialised in a constructor... If it's within the class then the scope can be `private` and you should declare your array variable at the top of the file, then in the constructor initialise it and it will be available for use by all methods within that class i.e. `this.array`.

Comment: sorry I know that it was a poor question I will try to make a simplified example so I can post some code.

Comment: sorry @px06 how can I use this.array?

Comment: So before the constructor you want to define `int[] missed` and in the constructor you can initialise it like `missed = new int[3]` and then you will be able to access that array (given it is initialised before accessing) in the methid `questionsMissed()`. It's a little bit like what you're doing with the char array `correctAnswers` but note that you shouldn't be calling `char correctAnswers = {..}` because it has already been assigned a type.

Comment: @px06 I have actually tried that but I recieve a java.lang.NullPointerException. Is it also fine to be populating the array in the constructor like I am doing?

Comment: I've added in an answer to help you, take a look and see if it works for your case.

Comment: @px06 sorry its not giving me that error any more. Its just not registering anything being in the array when I run the program. Everything else works fine and if I put a print statement in the constructor it shows that the array has the elements in it. But in the questionsMissed() method I am just writing return missed; would that be correct?

Comment: Yes but `return` doesn't print, it, well returns. You can do `System.out.println(questionsMissed());` and that would print it. I have updated the answer to guide you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some suggestions in the comments of the code below, you should be able to access `missed` like below but if you're instantiating the class `Example` then the `missed` array will also be initialised so, you shouldn't get any NPE here.

Also note that `missed = new int[3];` will yield an array like `[0,0,0]` until you assign it some values.

```
public class Example {

    private char[] correctAnswers;
    private char[] studentAnswers;

    private int[] missed; // here you're defining the array, this can be used throughout the class.

    private int count = 0;

    // Constructor accepts an array of answers from the other program.
    public Example(char[] answers) {
        correctAnswers = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'}; // Here, don't call char[] again because you've already defined this array as char[] earlier
        int question_number = 1;
        missed = new int[0]; // here you are initialising the array with 3 elements

        // Copy answers array to studentAnswers array
        *Insert code here 

        //Using a for loop I Compare the two arrays studentAnswers and 
        //correctAnswers and increment variables count and question_number
        //and if a question is wrong I populate the missed array with 
        // the question_number
        *Insert code here*

        for(int i=0; i<studentAnswers.length(); i++){

            if(studentAnswers[i] != correctAnswers[i]){
                missed = addElement(missed, i); // Adding an element to the list, this isn't a good way to do it
            }

        }

    }

    public int totalCorrect() {
        return count;
    }

    public int[] totalIncorrect() {
        incorrect = 3 - count;
        return incorrect;
    }

    // This method can't accept any arguments
    public int[] questionsMissed() {
        try {
            return missed;  // You can access this, and return only if it has been initialised before accessing this method.
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("the array wasn't initialised before accessing this method")
        }
    }

    /**
      * This method just takes the current array, makes a new one and adds an element to it, it's mocking Collections.add(E e) 
    */
    static int[] addElement(int[] a, int e) {
        a  = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
        a[a.length - 1] = e;
        return a;
    }

}
```

Edit: I've added in some more suggestions on how you can achieve what you're trying to do but using arrays here seems like a really bad choice. I think you would be better off using [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). Because `missed` doesn't need to be initialised with the length of `3` unless all `3` answers were wrong.

Comment: You are the best person ever, thankyou so much for taking the time to help me! It is working now but when I remove the char[] before correct answers in the constructor as you suggest i get an error: illegal start of expression so I put it back but I removed the int[] before missed in the constructor like you have in your example and now it works...

Comment: @Doc_Apes no worries, and yeah I just realised that I did it wrong; fixed. Use it now the way I've done it and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks heaps I have it working now! You are a legend! Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

In some way you still have to make it accessible for the method you want to use it it.

- You can make the object publicly visible, (not reccommended)
- Use the command or builder pattern. Actually this is still adding it as a parameter, but you can have an empty cTor, and add it before you call the build/execute after you done so. I think this will fix your problem though.